# Limpiar una tabla

Tags: javascript, html

De antemano les agradezco la ayuda que me puedan dar con esto. Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es vaciar o limpiar una tabla que se trae datos de una BD mediante una consulta. Normalmente cuando quiero limpiar un input solo uso comillas:

```
document.getElementById('txtConsultaFolio').value = ''
```

pero en en el caso de una tabla que tendria que poner para limpiarla???, por que cuando quiero hacer otra consulta, los datos de la anterior siguen alli, como ya explique lo unico que quiero es limpiar la tabla.
Gracias de antemano

esta es mi tabla

```
<table  id = "tablaFolio" class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Lote</th>
          <th>Tabla</th>
          <th>Cajas</th>
          <th>Peso Por Tarima</th>
          <th>Peso Neto</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
      </table>
```

en el tbody es donde se muestra la tabla de los datos de la BD.

Comment: Necesitamos ver un [mre] del error, para ver el error que tengas, debes hacerlo visible para nosotros.

Comment: no es que tenga un error como tal, simplemente no encuentro la forma para hacerlo para limpiar la tabla despues de una consulta, por eso puse el ejemplo de value = ' '

Comment: document.getElementById('tablaFolio').innerHTML="";

Comment: Claro pero mira te explico. Acá no veo una tabla con datos, ni como tratas de limpiarla. Por que además debo saber cuando estas tratando de limpiarla... con un botón? la quieres limpiar durante/despues de un proceso? etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.- La forma fácil:**

Puedes ocupar [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) para limpiarla, está es la forma más fácil de hacerlo.

```js
function limpiarTodo(){
  document.getElementById("tablaFolio").innerHTML="";
}

function limpiarBody(){
  document.getElementById("tablaFolio").querySelector("tbody").innerHTML="";
}
```

```html
<table  id = "tablaFolio" class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
     <tr>
          <th>Lote</th>
          <th>Tabla</th>
          <th>Cajas</th>
          <th>Peso Por Tarima</th>
          <th>Peso Neto</th>
          <th></th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
<tbody>

       <tr>
          <th>1</th>
          <th>1</th>
          <th>1</th>
          <th>1</th>
          <th>1</th>
          <th>1</th>
      </tr>
             <tr>
          <th>2</th>
          <th>2</th>
          <th>2</th>
          <th>2</th>
          <th>2</th>
          <th>2</th>
      </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<button onclick="limpiarTodo()">Limpiar Toda la tabla</button>
<button onclick="limpiarBody()">Limpiar body</button>
```

**2.- Mediante la iteracion de nodos**

Otra forma seria eliminar por nodos usando [removeChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild)

```js
function limpiarTodo(){
   removerChildNodes(document.getElementById("tablaFolio"));
}

function limpiarBody(){
    removerChildNodes(document.getElementById("tablaFolio").querySelector("tbody"));
}

function removerChildNodes(padre) {
    while (padre.firstChild) {
        padre.removeChild(padre.firstChild);
    }
}
```

```html
<table  id = "tablaFolio" class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
     <tr>
          <th>Lote</th>
          <th>Tabla</th>
          <th>Cajas</th>
          <th>Peso Por Tarima</th>
          <th>Peso Neto</th>
          <th></th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
<tbody>

       <tr>
          <th>1</th>
          <th>1</th>
          <th>1</th>
          <th>1</th>
          <th>1</th>
          <th>1</th>
      </tr>
             <tr>
          <th>2</th>
          <th>2</th>
          <th>2</th>
          <th>2</th>
          <th>2</th>
          <th>2</th>
      </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<button onclick="limpiarTodo()">Limpiar Toda la tabla</button>
<button onclick="limpiarBody()">Limpiar body</button>
```

Comment: esta era la respuesta que ocupaba